# How to get rid of the initial load time

Tags: wordpress, optimization, web

im trying to optimize the loading of a website im working on... in dev tools, im seeing a 3s initial wait time. I dont understand what it represents and how to avoid it.

[image: here is a snapshot of the dev tools timeline:]

the website address is http://www.seneca.ca/

thanks a lot

Comment: Move your site to better server

Comment: well that doesn't sound like very valid answer, and btw the servers are WP engine - so they should be pretty decent for wordpress websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how the bar for the load of the page is color coded. First gray, then green, then blue. The gray part is DNS lookups and initiating the request to the server. The green part represents the amount of time it takes the server to start responding to the request. The blue part is the time spent downloading the HTML.

@batz's comment may not have been helpful, but is basically correct—3 seconds for the server to start responding is far too slow. It needs to be more like 200ms or less ideally, but at a minimum under 1 second. It could indicate that the server is just underpowered and you need to move your site to a better server.

Alternately, if your pages do not change often, caching the pages as static html files and serving those instead of directly connecting to the dynamic pages will do wonders to speed page delivery. Sounds like you are using WordPress. If so, I'd check out one of these plugins: W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache.

It could also just be your personal connection. I ran the same page through WebPageTest over a 5mbps connection and it loads decently fast (not blindingly fast, but pretty good).
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160525_Y9_K5Q/

Comment: ive adjusted a lot of settings since I posted this. the site is ok now... ive had to use a "cache warmer"[link] https://wordpress.org/plugins/warm-cache/ and make sure it continuously crawls all pages. I believe the site has quite a few plugins/programming issues making the server take longer than it should to answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Based on the WPT results, it wont get much faster on the WP end (server-side). The main thing slowing it down now is the client-side. Especially the 9 custom fonts being loaded and all the non-async js includes.

Comment: can I just put all js script to be async with the technique described here: https://ikreativ.com/async-with-wordpress-enqueue/ is there any downsides to it?

Comment: yes, seems like that would do it. Downsides is you dont control the order of execution, so make sure they are not dependant on each other or that they wait until the dependencies are loaded. Backward compat isnt really an issue -- browsers that dont understand async will just load them normally.